# What happens if a 7.1 audio stream is outputted by a 5.1 soundcard?

Tags: audio-interfaces, 5.1, 7.1

Just out of curiosity since I want to use the Asus Xonar DGX with 5.1 compatibility, and there are quite a lot of streams and movies out there which offer 7.1 audio streams.

Comment: Nothing. Your sound card isn't capable of 7.1. It'll just play 5.1.